# I get mysql error: #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1242

Table "*lss_character_factions*":

| character_id | faction_id | rank | duty_time | duty_total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 3 | 100 | 200 |

Table "*lss_faction*":

| id | faction_name |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | Police |

Table "*lss_faction_ranks*":

| faction_id | rank_id | rank_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 3 | Cadet |

I want to get:

- "*lss_character_factions.faction_id*"
- "*lss_character_factions.duty_time*"
- "*lss_character_factions.duty_total*",
- "*lss_faction.faction_name*",
- "*lss_faction_ranks.rank_name*"

when "*lss_character_factions.character_id*" equals 1.

I have tried using join operations, but doesn't seem to work properly as I get multiple rows from the subquery instead of only one as expected. Here's my coding attempt:

```
SELECT (SELECT lss_character_factions.character_id
        FROM lss_character_factions
        WHERE lss_character_factions.character_id = 1) AS faction_id,
       (SELECT lss_faction.name
        FROM lss_faction, lss_character_factions
        WHERE lss_faction.id = lss_character_factions.faction_id) AS faction_name,
       (SELECT lss_faction_ranks.name
        FROM lss_faction_ranks, lss_character_factions
        WHERE lss_character_factions.rank = lss_faction_ranks.rank_id 
          AND lss_character_factions.faction_id = lss_faction_ranks.faction_id) AS faction_rank,
       (SELECT lss_character_factions.dutytime
        FROM lss_character_factions
        WHERE lss_character_factions.character_id = 1) AS faction_dutytime,
       (SELECT lss_character_factions.totalduty
        FROM lss_character_factions
        WHERE lss_character_factions.character_id = 1) AS faction_totalduty
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

> Error: #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Can you help with this problem?

Note: I can't alter the schema of the database.

Comment: Your second subquery isn't correlated with the first one. So it's returning all faction names.

Comment: There is no outer query here, no subqueries are correlated, therefore all subqueries can potentially return more than one rows. It is your database, you can run each subquery separately and see what they return! I honestly wonder what the purpose of this query is and why you use subqueries instead of writing a proper query joining all relevant tables!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have explained to you

Answer (score 0):

The issue of your query is that your filtering operation (the `WHERE` clause in your first subquery) should be applied to all your subqueries.

Though you can largely improve your code by:

- applying the filtering as first operation
- removing subqueries and using join operations directly
- (optional but recommended) declare join operations explicitly, using the `ON` clause for each of them

The final query should look like this:

```
WITH character_id_1 AS (
    SELECT faction_id,
           duty_time,
           duty_total
    FROM lss_character_factions
    WHERE character_id = 1
)
SELECT c.*,
       f.faction_name,
       r.rank_name
FROM       character_id_1 c
INNER JOIN lss_faction f
        ON c.faction_id = f.id
INNER JOIN lss_faction_ranks r
        ON f.id = r.faction_id
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sE97TKQc12UneSXZxeQdwp/0).

Note: If you want to learn more on joins in MySQL, you can find many examples and full details at the [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html).